# Two authentication modes in Testlink

Tags: authentication, ldap, testlink

I've just installed Testlink and am trying to get familiar with it.
I've even managed to configure authentication using LDAP (Microsoft AD).
But strangely, as soon as I set LDAP as default authentication method, my local test users cannot log on anymore.
If I change back to DB authentication as default auth method, my LDAP users cannot log in anymore.

I've the following set in the configuration file:

```
$tlCfg->authentication['domain'] = array('DB','LDAP');
$tlCfg->authentication['method'] = 'LDAP';
```

It seems as if both authentication modes are enabled and LDAP is used as the default.
When editing the user settings of a user, I have a dropdown box named "Authentication method"
It has three entries. One is "Default", the other is "0" and the third is "1".
This led me to the assumption, that I can select the type of authentication used for this account.
But strangely, regardless of which option I choose, the behavior is identical to what I mentioned above.

Is anyone experienced in Testlink?
Does anyone use two authentication modes in parallel with Testlink?
Did anyone see the same issue before? What did you do to solve this issue?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Best regards,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

You can use testlink DB authentication as well as LDAP authentication. You have to set this option when you create user

Comment: I see the drop down box, but regardless of what I select, the authentication mode does not change and is the same for all users.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown box named "Authentication method" has three entries. One is "Default (LDAP)", the other is "DB" and the third is "LDAP". If you see different options then something is messed up with your TestLink installation. I'm using v1.9.14 on MySQL.